# Why do magically shrunken people speak with such high voices?

Tags: trope

In many films/television series/videogames, a character who has been reduced to minuscule size either by magic or advanced technology suddenly starts to speak with a very high-pitched, squeaky voice- has there ever been a reason stated for this?

Comment: It's probably just done to follow a trope most of the time. Practically speaking, pitch (frequency) has an associated wavelength in a given medium; a tuned apparatus for creating a sound in air will produce a certain frequency for a given length - longer for lower pitches, shorter for higher pitches. If an apparatus is shrunk down in size, it would make sense that it will generate sound at a higher pitch.

Comment: In agreement with @AnthonyX contrast the pitch range ([tessitura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessitura)) of a  violin compared to a cello compared to a double bass. These instruments are structurally *very* similar, with a primary difference being in their respective sizes: smaller corresponds to higher pitch range.

Comment: Shorter and thinner vocal cords are associated with higher pitched voices in real life--this is a main reason children mostly have higher voices than adults, and women mostly have higher voices than men (see [this article](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/72393/why-are-girls-voices-usually-higher-boys-voices)). We can also control the pitch of our voices to some degree, but that's done by using muscles that contract or stretch the vocal cords.

Comment: Why all the votes to close? I thought it was a fair question.

Comment: @Nu'Daq FWIW, I voted to close because it's simply a question of real-world physics.  The range of frequencies that can be produced by a tiny (mammalian) vocal apparatus are higher than the range from larger ones.  Mice and bats make very high-pitched vocalizations, bears make low-pitched vocalizations; small dogs are higher-pitched than large ones, etc.

Comment: @DavidW- yeah but I wasn't talking about real world creatures now was I?

Comment: @Nu'Daq - I voted to close because it's asking about a trope rather than a specific work. This isn't true for all shrunken creatures, just some.

Comment: @Valorum And yet, [genre trope questions not specific to a single work are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9760/31394).

Comment: I thought it was physically an issue of wavelength: larger bodies can produce longer wavelength sounds.  Then, since speed of sound is close to constant and equal to wavelength times frequency, a longer wavelength corresponds to a lower frequency.

Comment: This is an actual physical effect. Have you ever heard a Chihuahua bark like a Great Dane, or vice versa?

Comment: Where this is more trope than anything else is when the shrunken person takes on a high-pitched voice only as perceived by others at "normal" scale; when two shrunken people converse with each other, their voices remain unchanged. The trope only comes from the viewer's expectation that smaller things make higher-pitched sounds, which does have a basis in physics, but  on-screen presentations "bend science" so the viewer gets the idea and can follow along without having to work too hard at either thinking or listening.

Comment: I was going to VTC on the basis of Real World Physics question... but I didn't.  Thinking about it, the answer isn't Real World Physics, it's that most writers are adhering to an observed /know real world principle.  It's a subtle difference, but I'd argue it makes it a question more about writers intent than physics.  I.e., the answer being 'It's a known trait in the Real World, and authors tend to incorporated it into their stories/magic.', consistent with what Pete says [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/261023/2292)

Comment: @Anthony_X that's just to make life easier for the viewer. It's like the actors in the "Lion King" musical wearing animal masks. One suspends disbelief.  And, do mice hear other mice as squeaky? The same physics that makes their voices high-pitched, also moves the range of their hearing upwards. So a mouse should sound "normal" to another mouse (although we can't ever know exactly what it's like to be a mouse).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the real world smaller versions of things tend to make higher sounds than big things.

Think of :

- a double bass vs a violin
- a big drum vs a small drum
- a big drill vs a small drill
- the bong of a big bell vs the ting of a small bell.

The actual mechanical reasons why this happens may vary from object to object, but the common experience is that small things make higher sounds than large versions of the same thing.

It's really only logical to think that a person shrunk by magic or SF-handwavium would find their voice getting higher.

Comment: Technically the _production_ of the sound is a function of the strings, not the body.  The the body (soundboard) is sized to preferentially amplify the correct range of notes, but it doesn't _produce_ them.

Comment: A better analogy would be with the strings of a piano or harp.

Comment: @DavidW: Drums and bells don't have strings.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't say anything about drums or bells.  What do drums or bells have to do with my comment?  Strings are a decent analogy for vocal cords, and a piano (or harp) makes the relationship between length and pitch very clear.

Comment: @DavidW: The answer to which your comment is attached references both of those objects. If your comment is not a response to this answer, then it should perhaps be posted as a separate answer.

Comment: More accurate would be to say that it's a function of the vibrating part of the thing. A small stringed instrument has a short string, a small drum has a smaller drumhead.

Comment: Although in wind instruments the vibrating thing is the air cavity -- that's why a piccolo is higher than a flute.

Comment: @Kevin Is there a stack overflow rule or guideline stating that a comment must address the entirety of an answer?

Comment: @nasch: DavidW's comment does not appear to address *any* part of this answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: @DavidW Stringed instruments are a *poor* analogy for human vocol chords as compared with, say, *reed* instruments, or other instruments, such as the bull-roarer or kazoo, which produce sound through the oscillation of a flexible membrane as perturbed by a sustained air current (which is how our vocal chords produce sound, not via percussive  striking *a la* piano, or plucking *a la* harp or guitar).

Comment: @Kevin Perhaps you should look at the state of the answer when I posted my comment?  There was literally no mention of bells in it.

Comment: @Kevin When DavidW mentioned "strings" and the "soundboard" he was referring to this part of the answer: "a double bass vs a violin"

Comment: @DavidW I did look at the first revision of the answer. No bells, but it wasn't only talking about stringed instruments, so without specifying which part of the answer you were responding to your comment looks a little odd. The fact that it appears to be worded as correcting a claim that doesn't appear in the answer (that the production of the sound of a stringed instrument is a function of the body) is also why you got the responses you did. It's just a random fact about stringed instruments; more *detailed* but not more *accurate*, and not in any way that's very relevant to the topic.

Comment: I don't know if it's because I'm a piano amateur but when I read @DavidW's comment, I instantly understood what they meant and how it's related to the answer. There was this video of the world's tiniest piano, which did make funny high pitched noises because of its size.

Comment: A better comparison might be between a large dog and a small one.  Your average Great Dane or Russian Wolfhound has a much deeper bark than a Chihuahua or a Pekingese.  The same is often true of little people - compare Verne Troyer or Warwick Davis to more average- or large-sized people.  There are of course exceptions - Peter Dinklage vs. Mike Tyson are some unusual outliers at opposite ends with voices that might be unexpected for their size...

Answer (score 28):

There's a bit of artistic license I'd say due to Pete's answer that we expect small things to sound higher pitched than big things.

But actually, the character has smaller vocal chords now, so they would likely vibrate at a higher frequency and therefore make a higher pitched sound.

Answer (score 16):

Providing the physics background to the other answers:

Sound is transmitted as a wave. The frequency of the sound generally corresponds to what we know as pitch. The frequency **f** is inversely related to the wave length **λ** via the speed of sound **c**, as in **f = c/λ** or **λ = c/f**. In other words, the higher the frequency (pitch) of a wave, the shorter your wave, or the longer the wave the lower your frequency.

Any noise is just swinging air molecules that reach your ear. Music instruments will vibrate (i.e. a swinging string or drumhead, a vibrating triangle, a "vibrating" air column in a flute). The lowest possible note will have the longest wave length and corresponds to the string length, air cavity etc.

As the other answers have pointed out, smaller people have smaller vocal chords, which are, grossly simplified, like a guitar or violin string. Thus they can not create as low notes as humans with regularly sized vocal chords.

Comment: +1 However, a technical niggle: "The frequency of the sound is what we know as pitch." This is technically false in quite a similar way that saying "frequency of light and color are the same thing" is false: [frequency is a physical property, but pitch is a perceptual property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(music)#Pitch_and_frequency), and the relationship between the two is complex. Psychoacoustics is weird and amazing. :) Also sound waves are longitudinal waves, not transverse waves, so "swinging" is not quite apt.

Answer (score 3):

just physics.

long vocal cord means long wavelength means low frequency, short vocal cord means short wavelength means high frequency.

Its is the same reason for that small speakers like in the smartphone are not able to produce good bass.

Comment: Well, it's also the mass, and the length of the vocal cavity, but both of those scale as the length of the vocal cords.

Comment: Can you give an example when mass changes oscillation frequency? Consider the experiment in school where you have a pendulum. Its frequency is only dependent of its length, but not of its mass.

Comment: It's not oscillation frequency, IIRC, it's about resonant frequencies.

Comment: @DavidW Right, although resonant frequencies affect the timbre rather than the fundamental frequency itself in vocal acoustics.